# Read online excel spreadsheet with Kotlin

Tags: excel, kotlin

I need to read data from online excel spreadsheet and use this data in my Kotlin program.

I tried to do it like this this

```
val url = URL("https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiTc_S77bVGsgifs9WIHLXMVobPP?e=rgszMB")
val connection = url.openConnection()
val excel = connection.getInputStream()
val xlWb = WorkbookFactory.create(excel)
```

But I get the error

```
 java.io.IOException: Can't open workbook - unsupported file type: HTML
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:203)
```

Making InputStream buffered also didn't help

```
val excel = connection.getInputStream().buffered()
```

There's a lot of info of reading plain xls/xlsx files, but I cannot find anything about online excel. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you share url of sample online excel spreadsheet?

Comment: @ishallwin There's a link to the spreadsheet, I didn't replace it on purpose. https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiTc_S77bVGsgifs9WIHLXMVobPP?e=rgszMB

Comment: Looks like it's not a direct link to an excel, but rather a link to one-drive viewer with a excel sheet being requested right away... And you error tell you that HTML cannot be treated as excel. So you'll need to figure out how to get an excel from that link, or get link directly to excel file.

Comment: @Demigod Yeah, makes sense. But that's the problem I haven't figured out the way to get an excel from that link.